# Stack Level Too deep SystemStackError in FriendshipsController#request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stack

I Only get this error in web tests. Tested every single line through command line and everything worked. The requested, accepted, friends - everything gets displayed and added correctly. But when I try to use the web forms, I always get that **Stack level too deep system error pointing at the controller and passing correct Parameters:{"id"=>"3"}**

**User.rb**

```
has_many :friendships

  has_many :friends,
           :through => :friendships,
           :source => :friend,
           :conditions => "status = 'accepted'",
           :order => :created_at


  has_many :requested_friends,
           :through => :friendships,
           :source => :friend,
           :conditions => "status = 'requested'",
           :order => :created_at
```

**friendship.rb**

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user, :friend, :status, :user_id, :friend_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'friend_id'

  def self.request(user, friend)
    return false if are_friends(user, friend)
    return false if user == friend
    f1 = self.new(:user_id => user.id, :friend_id => friend.id, :status => "pending")
    f2 = self.new(:user_id => friend.id, :friend_id => user.id, :status => "requested")
    transaction do
      f1.save
      f2.save
    end
  end
def self.are_friends(user, friend)
    return false if user == friend
    return true unless find_by_user_id_and_friend_id_and_status(user, friend, "accepted").nil?
    return true unless find_by_user_id_and_friend_id_and_status(friend, user, "accepted").nil?
    false
  end

  def self.are_friends_pending(user, friend)
    return false if user == friend
    return true unless find_by_user_id_and_friend_id_and_status(user, friend, "pending").nil?
    return true unless find_by_user_id_and_friend_id_and_status(friend, user, "requested").nil?
    false
  end
```

**FriendshipsController**

```
def request
    @user = current_user
    @friend = User.find(params[:id])
    unless @friend.nil?
      if Friendship.request(@user, @friend)
        flash[:notice] = "friend request sent"
      else
        flash[:notice] = "friend request could not be sent"
      end
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

**_userlist.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <% User.each do |f|%>

        <li>

            <%= link_to "#{f.full_name}", user_path(f.id)%>
            <% if Friendship.are_friends(current_user.id,f.id)%>
            <label class="label">is a friend</label>
            <%else%>
            <%= link_to "Add Friend", addfriend_friendships_path(:id => f.id)%>
            <%end%>

        </li>
        <%end%>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
   resources :friendships do
    collection do
      get 'request',:as=>"addfriend"
      get 'accept',:as=>"accept_fr"
      get 'reject',:as=>"reject_fr"
    end
  end
```

Because everything works in command line i don't really understand why i get that error. Can anyone see the problem with this ?

Comment: can you pls post your params?

Comment: Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"3"} it does pass the correct ids, sorry about late replay

Comment: You're missing the definition for `are_friends` method - can you please add that?

Comment: Added copy of the methods to Friendships.rb . didn't think there is anything wrong with them, as they work in command line and in view checks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions,

Rename your controller method, `request` I imagine would be too similar to a http request, I'd suggest `request_friendship` or similar.

Don't use `redirect_to :back`, try just redirecting to a particular path/URL and see whether that fixes anything.

I'm afraid there's not enough info in the question to definitively give an answer so just guessing really...

Comment: redirecting doesn't affect it. The 'Request' method name doesn't affect it either, i get the same problem with accept and reject methods. added the routes to the post, don't know what else can it be.